# Is there a difference in terms of algorithm efficiency between subtracting ASCII values and simply subtracting an integer?

Tags: java, algorithm

I recently completed TopCoder algorithm contest single round match 618, and the problem was quite simple. Given a string consisting only of capital letters from A to Z, A = 1, B = 2, etc. and Z = 26. The objective was to return the string's total value using these values.

This was my algorithm:

```
public class WritingWords {
  public int write(String word) {
    int total = 0;
    word = word.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
      total += (int)word.charAt(i)-64;
    }

    return total;
  }
}
```

I obtained a score of ~165/250.

This is the code of another user who got ~249/250:

```
public class WritingWords {
  public int write(String word) {
    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
      total += word.charAt(i)-'A'+1;
    }

    return total;
  }
}
```

To me, the two source codes look very similar, and I'm unsure as to why I might have gotten such a lower score. What might be the reason that the latter algorithm is so much more efficient than mine? Seems to me that they'd both run in O(n) time anyways.

Comment: First you don't need the `replaceAll` given that the question says the string consists only of letters. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

> Given a string consisting only of capital letters from A to Z, A = 1, B = 2, etc. and Z = 26.

Given that problem statement, this line

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

is useless and iterates over the whole `String` value pointlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Both `total += (int)word.charAt(i)-64;` and `total += word.charAt(i)-'A'+1;` would run pretty much equally fast. The problem is in this line here:

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

This line (which is only in your code) is what slows down your program. As you can see in the other response, this line is unnecassary.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
total += word.charAt(i) - 64;
```

is exactly the same as

```
total += (int) word.charAt(i) - 64;
```

which is the same as

```
total += word.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;
```

If you want to speed up your program, don't use a regular expression

```
public int write(String word) {
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 'A')
            total += word.charAt(i) - 64;
    }

    return total;
}
```